# Page breaks in hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, page-breaking, texlive

While following [Manual hyphenation in text part of \href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646649/manual-hyphenation-in-text-part-of-href), I wondered how TeXLive handles `\href` hyperlinks with line breaks in its text part if the parts before and after the break end up on separate pages. The PDF document should then contain:

- the part of the hyperlink text before the line break (clickable)
- the footer of the first page (non-clickable)
- the header of the second page (non-clickable)
- the part of the hyperlink text after the line break (clickable)

The following document illustrates this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent A\vadjust{\vfill\break} \href{http://a.co}{very \hfill\break long} hyperlink
\end{document}
```

I tried it out in Overleaf, with TeXLive 2021-06-01, and found that the result depends on the compiler:

| Compiler | Treatment of clickable parts | Space at the right of first line | Page footer and header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LaTeX | placed in an extra `\hbox` | no line-breaking possible | no page-breaking possible |
| pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX | enclosed in in `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink` | clickable | whole lines clickable |
| XeLaTeX | enclosed in `pdf:bann` and `pdf:eann` | not clickable | only the page number clickable |

I learned from the comments to the other question that versions of TeXLive newer than 2021-06-01 do not make the footer/header clickable, and would be interested how these enclose the clickable parts (again, using the different compilers). At the moment, Overleaf does not offer these TeXLive versions.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/2388